# Reorder according variable of melted dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, melt

I've datas as follow:

```
DF=structure(list(experiment = c("BR", "CH", "EP", "IP", "JU", "MA", 
"SA", "ST", "SV", "VI"), duration = c(28L, 9L, 20L, 4L, 14L, 
30L, 26L, 23L, 17L, 6L), percentage_total_exp = c(47.2222222222222, 
51.063829787234, 52.3809523809524, 79.0322580645161, 48.6842105263158, 
72.7272727272727, 62.0689655172414, 34.469696969697, 61.1111111111111, 
34.8837209302326), nb_reaction = c(29, 29, 14, 11, 40, 11, 14, 
14, 23, 18)), .Names = c("experiment", "duration", "percentage_total_exp", 
"nb_reaction"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I melted my datas in order to show then as the following ggplot

```
meltR=melt(DF)
ggplot(meltR, aes(x=experiment , y = value, group = variable, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge")
```

Now the problem is, that I want to have 3 versions of this plot. One ordered by variable : `duration`, and the second by variable : `percentage_total_exp` and the last by variable :  `nb_reaction`.

I don't know how to specify this. I tried `y = reorder(value, -duration)` but in fact it didnt recognize duration. Is melting is a bad idea in this case ? how to do this ?

EDIT 2 : minimal code to add because my `experiment` name are in reality very long

```
plots <- lapply(levels(meltR$variable), function(lev) {
  meltR$experiment <- factor(meltR$experiment, levels = meltR$experiment[order(meltR$value[meltR$variable == lev])])
  ggplot(meltR, aes(x=experiment , y = value, group = variable, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge") + ggtitle(lev) + theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10, angle=45, hjust=1, vjust=1, face="bold"))
    })
grid.arrange(grobs = plots)
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`duration` is not of column name but a factor level of the column named `variable` in your example. Thus, it does not work that way. One option could be to loop over the three factor levels or `variable`, reorder them according to `value` and then plot. Here's how it could work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(gridExtra)
DF=structure(list(experiment = c("BR", "CH", "EP", "IP", "JU", "MA", 
"SA", "ST", "SV", "VI"), duration = c(28L, 9L, 20L, 4L, 14L, 
30L, 26L, 23L, 17L, 6L), percentage_total_exp = c(47.2222222222222, 
51.063829787234, 52.3809523809524, 79.0322580645161, 48.6842105263158, 
72.7272727272727, 62.0689655172414, 34.469696969697, 61.1111111111111, 
34.8837209302326), nb_reaction = c(29, 29, 14, 11, 40, 11, 14, 
14, 23, 18)), .Names = c("experiment", "duration", "percentage_total_exp", 
"nb_reaction"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
meltR=melt(DF)
plots <- lapply(levels(meltR$variable), function(lev) {
  meltR$experiment <- factor(meltR$experiment, levels = meltR$experiment[order(-meltR$value[meltR$variable == lev])])
  ggplot(meltR, aes(x=experiment , y = value, group = variable, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge") + ggtitle(lev)
})
grid.arrange(grobs = plots)
```

[image]

Comment: So nice !! thanks a lot :) ! last point, did it support adding a theme ? (see my edit). When I add it I have no values in my plot :/

Comment: It does not make any difference whether you add a theme or not; e.g. `plots <- lapply(levels(meltR$variable), function(lev) {
  meltR$experiment <- factor(meltR$experiment, levels = meltR$experiment[order(-meltR$value[meltR$variable == lev])])
  ggplot(meltR, aes(x=experiment , y = value, group = variable, fill = variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge") + 
    ggtitle(lev) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
}); grid.arrange(grobs = plots)` works, too.

Comment: oh I see, I have no bar because axis title were to long so there wasn't any bar, now all is ok, thanks a lot for your help !